# Bonobo Git Server 5.1.1 gives empty blank page on Windows 7

Tags: windows, bonobo

Bonobo Git Server 5.1.1 always shows blank page in windows 7 but IIS 7 is up and running (Tried with almost 5 windows 7 PCs). I tried all the options and selected asp.net 4.0 still no success.
But I tried in Windows 8 there I am getting the login page successfully.
What could be the issue? Please help me on this regard

Comment: Have you checked the Pre-requisites. .Net 4.6 is required